# Are there any top like utilities for real time HTTP traffic analysis

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, log-files, apache2

Near real time is also okay, I guess it will be possible say by parsing the access log continuously and show the real time status, e.g. most requested files, top remote ip.

I heard about these tool before but cannot remember the name of it.

Any one know?

Comment: nethogs, iptraf, iftraf etc..

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GoAccess](https://www.goaccess.io) an opensource real time web log analyser for both [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) and [Ngix](http://nginx.org/) which is able to run on any *nix terminal or web browser.

You can download it [here](https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess)